# Generating letters in Docx generates empty letters

Tags: civireport

Generating letters in Docx generates empty letters and with office 365 images are oversized even if image size is locked

Comment: Civi version? Also do you mean using a docx uploaded template or just choosing output format docx?

Comment: Yes but the civi CRM uses openoffice which supports only basic HTML formatting.

Comment: Can you edit the original question to say which version of CiviCRM you are using and list the steps you are doing?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11753)

Answer (score 1):

In our experience using docx with the core features only works for very simple templates. Have a look at the CiviOffice Extension instead. It's still in development but could already do want you want: https://docs.civicrm.org/civioffice/en/latest/